# Use Elmah with twitter and its mandatory oauth authentication?

Tags: .net, twitter, oauth, elmah

Since Twitter won't use basic authentication (login, password) anymore, I'm converting my app to using twitter with oauth authentication. In my code this was ok, but I also use Elmah to tweet the errors on a specific twitter account. But it seems Elmah only works with basic authentication. Is it true? Any workaround?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added [an issue on the Elmah web site](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/issues/detail?id=183&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary) and it has been accepted.

In the meantime, I'm trying to find a workaround but no success. My try was to add an event for error filtering but I get another issue, explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3636032/elmah-errorlog-filtering-event-handler-not-called-under-iis7). By doing this I would not filter the error but instead I would [post it to twitter manually](http://tweetsharp.codeplex.com/).