# Elmah: ErrorLog_Filtering event handler not called under IIS7

Tags: asp.net, web-config, elmah

I enable error log filtering within Elmah and want to do it programmatically in a ErrorLog_Filtering event handler. It works well under Visual Studio dev server but as soon as I go under IIS7 (local on my dev machine or remote on my web server), the handler is not called (error logging works well).

Here is my usual web.config:

```
<configuration>

  <configSections>

    <sectionGroup name="elmah">
      <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorTweet" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorTweetSectionHandler, Elmah" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <elmah>
    <errorLog type="Elmah.SqlErrorLog, Elmah" connectionStringName="ShopMvcConnectionString" />
  </elmah>

  <system.web>

    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
    </httpHandlers>

    <httpModules>
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" />
    </httpModules>

  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>

    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="Elmah.ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="Elmah.ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>

    <handlers>
      <add name="Elmah" path="elmah.axd" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

and my handler in Global.asax:

```
public void ErrorLog_Filtering(object sender, ExceptionFilterEventArgs e)
{
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason your handler in not being called under IIS 7 is because you *named* the module differently. You named it `ErrorLog` under `system.web/httpModules` and then `Elmah.ErrorLog` under `system.webServer/modules`.

[Handling module events in `Global.asax`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szzd570s%28VS.71%29.aspx) works via a naming convention where the event handler must be named after the module name as found in the configuration followed by an underscore (`_`), followed by the event name. `ErrorLog_Filtering` is fine and matches the registered name under `system.web/httpModules` and which is being picked up by the [Visual Studio Development Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58wxa9w5.aspx). You just need to make sure that you match up all the names and it should work in both environments.

See also: [Programmatically log error and send email](http://groups.google.com/group/elmah/msg/37c0b69ec68318b0)

Comment: You are absolutely right. Thanks a lot. I guess I did some copy/paste and didn't realize the presence of the Elmah prefix.